# A first chance exception of type 'OracleInternal.NotificationServices.ONSException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2013, database-connection, oracle12c

my project is not working fine my app codes

```
string oradb = "DATA SOURCE=192.168.1.27:1521/TEST;DBA PRIVILEGE=SYSDBA;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=SYS;PASSWORD=1234";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb); // C#
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO URUNLER VALUES('" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox2.Text.Count() + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')";
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
            adapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
            conn.Dispose();
```

my *app.config* codes

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="OracleDbContext" connectionString="User Id=SYS;Password=1234;Data Source=192.168.1.27:1521/TEST"
  providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
<add name="WindowsFormsApplication17.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"
  connectionString="DATA SOURCE=192.168.1.27:1521/TEST;DBA PRIVILEGE=SYSDBA;PASSWORD=1234;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=SYS"
  providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
```

and

```
<dataSources>
    <dataSource alias="TEST" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.27)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TEST))) "/>
  </dataSources>
```

my *tnsnames.ora* file is;

```
LISTENER_TEST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.27)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.27)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = test)
    )
  )
```

thank u for helping

Comment: Merhaba Yusuf bey kardeşim. Your code seems vulnerable to sql injection ( use Oracle Procedures with bind variables), and get rid of connecting to SYS schema as soon as possible, connect to an ordinary schema for your projects instead.

Comment: Thank you Barbaros for your reply but I have just started to learn these jobs so I do not know how to get rid of SYS schemes

Comment: you're welcome Yusuf, need to consult your DBA particularly you're working at your office environment.